# Accessing a JFrame using an another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have 2 jframes,frame1 and frame2. I tried to inconfied frame1 using a jbutton on frame1. I coded jbutton like this.

```
this.setState(JFrame.iconfied);
```

and it was working.

Then I wanted to inconfied frame2 using the same jbutton (the button which was on frame1) I coded jbutton like this.

```
frame2 frame = new frame2();
frame.setState(JFrame.iconfied);
```

But it was not working.
"frame2" was the class name of frame2 and it was a public class, but the jbutton didn't do anything. If someone could help me I would appreciate that a lot! Thanks...

Comment: *"I have 2 jframes"* That's where this starts going wrong. Each application should have only one frame.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized what had happened with my code. I created an object named frame for frame2 class. Unfortunately I have created it inside of the method of jbutton which is called as jbuttonActionPerformed in Netbeans. So the object was executed at each time when I clicked the button. But the Object should be executed only one time. I override this simple rule and encountered that problem. After cut and pasted the object line outside of the method (but inside of the class) the problem was automatically fixed.